# Accessing Google's Blacklist Database API for Android Phone Application

Tags: android, filtering, spam

In Android phones, Google uses a **phone number blacklist database** in its phone application to prevent calls from known spam numbers. Calls from numbers registered in this database do not go through to the recipient.

**I have two questions regarding this:**

1 - Is there an API available for accessing this blacklist database?

2 - We need a constant sender ID that is consistently blacklisted. How can we obtain this?

I would greatly appreciate support and insights from those who are knowledgeable about this topic.

Comment: Android is not part of the Google Cloud Platform. Update your question tags to target the right audience. Also, I recommend including a link to the service you are using. Android and telephone numbers are a broad topic.